# C3P0 Connection Pool in JAVA

Tags: java, database, postgresql, connection, c3p0

In order to connect to the DB I use this command in try with resources line and after that I put my PreparedStatement:

```
try(conn = C3P0DataSource.getInstance().getConnection()){
.
.//Prepared Statement
.
}catch(SQLException e){
}
```

My C3P0DataSource class is:

```
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

public class C3P0DataSource {
private static C3P0DataSource dataSource;
private ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource;

private C3P0DataSource() {
    try {
        comboPooledDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        comboPooledDataSource.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver");
        comboPooledDataSource.setJdbcUrl("Server Address");
        comboPooledDataSource.setUser("My username");
        comboPooledDataSource.setPassword("My password");
        comboPooledDataSource.setMaxStatements( 180 ); 

        comboPooledDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(100);
    }catch (PropertyVetoException ex1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Main.splash_screen,
                "Missing PostgreSQL JDBC Driver",
                "Inane error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public static C3P0DataSource getInstance() {
    if (dataSource == null)
        dataSource = new C3P0DataSource();
    return dataSource;
}

public Connection getConnection() {
    Connection con = null;
    try {

        con = comboPooledDataSource.getConnection();
        if(con==null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Main.splash_screen,
                    "Connection couldn`t established...",
                    "Inane error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Main.splash_screen,
                "Connection couldn`t established...",
                "Inane error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return con;
}
```

}

I am using this method to connect to my PostgreSQL DB in a server through a VPN. It works fine when I have an internet connection and the VPN is on. But when I intentionally turn off the internet connection or the VPN to observe what is happening it goes into an infinity loop with lots of exceptions:

> (Aug 13, 2018 11:28:49 PM org.postgresql.Driver connect
>   SEVERE: Connection error: 
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:257)
>       at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:195)
>       at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)
>       at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
>       at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
>       at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>       at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
>       at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
>       at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
>       at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402)
>       at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
>       at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.(PGStream.java:69)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:156)
>       ... 13 more)

Until I turn the internet connection back on. My expected outcome is to put a timeout period when this process should end and pop the JOptionPane I showed above and then exit. How can I achieve this?

Comment: SOLVED i just needed to put setAcquireRetryAttempts(3);